# No solution worked of failed to authenticate on smtp server with username @gmail.com using 2 possible authenticators Laravel

Tags: laravel-5

I'm facing this failed to authenticate issue using 2 possible authenticators, I **tried almost all things** which others suggest
My Laravel 5 app Mail send from localhost through smtp but not on live server..
1- use less secure apps suggestion **which I already have selected **

2- Recaptcha issue (I clicked on [link](https://accounts.google.com/UnlockCaptcha) and unlock captcha, then Immediately try to send mail from my Laravel app but no success..

3- change password and again try send mail through app but no success.

4- use passwords in double quotations  but no success
My Mail only send through mandrill but go on spam folder.. **But It's separate issue please suggest me some thing which left from me..!**

Comment: are you using plain password for your `GMAIL SMTP` configuration ?

Comment: Dear what do you mean by Plain password? Using password in text in env file

Comment: Yes, how you use the password in your .env file `MAIL_PASSWORD=12345` or gmail encrypted password `MAIL_PASSWORD=wgfpedooyghpveep`

Comment: @Qazi yes I'm using plain password in mail_password

Comment: Okay then let me try to encrypt password.. But where does this from generate and then why mail sending from localhost?

Comment: ok, tell me that, the GMail acc, which you are using, has enable 2 step verification, If YES, then As per Gmail Policy you cannot use the plain password, you have to generate application specific password to use google services. [here](http://www.shoutmeloud.com/how-to-generate-google-app-specific-password-2-step-verification.html) its

Comment: Dear I haven't using any 2 step verification.. I have also open my mail accounts to different places to confirm It's not demanding any captcha

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103453/discussion-between-qazi-and-abdul-rehman).

Comment: I discussed on chat with @Qazi which is great, and he participate again to try these process which I mentioned above in my question and also some other for to manage. But At last suspect goes to my hosting which stopping connection, I don't know which thing but I used another driver for sending mail except Smtp. but Thanx Mr Qazi for you cooperation

Comment: Reham, You are welcome. I am glad that your issue is resolved.

Comment: Yes but with another driver :-)

Comment: Kindly add your solution as answer, and mark it answer, so other can take benefit.

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue was the result of the SMTP creds not getting pulled from the Environment file in Laravel.

So, I just set the mail settings directly in my `config/mail.php` file and that worked like a charm. But if you are worried about security you'd want to setup this file not to show up in your git repo.

Other people have had an issue when running the server under Artisan. So, to fix that you can try clearing the cache by running `php artisan cache:clear`

Comment: Thanks for adding you answer, but I've tried all the things, so what I know I've already commented here.Anyway Thanks https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35401072/no-solution-worked-of-failed-to-authenticate-on-smtp-server-with-username-gmail/45723575#comment-58594138

Comment: No worries. I just added this in here to perhaps help someone else who was  struggling with the same issue. Best of luck!